# ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters#encode_params tries to modify frozen strings and raises on upgrade from Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.2.16

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Basically, this seems to be https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7725 reported a year ago by a guy who stopped responding (heh http://xkcd.com/979/)

and I got this when upgrading from the very last Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.2.16.

The route in question serves HTML from model `Page` on routes of form `/en/contact` for example (from `config/routes.rb`)

```
# pages
STATIC_PAGES.each do |slug, desc|
  match ":language/#{slug}" => 'pages#static_page', :defaults => {:slug => slug, :language => 'en'}, :via => :get, :as => slug.underscore.to_s
end
```

My attempts to make a sample application that does the same thing and breaks have failed (copied relevant parts of the app into a new app, copied the `Gemfile` & `Gemfile.lock` and tried to reproduce, all went fine)

This is the stack trace: https://gist.github.com/bbozo/8315184 - not a single line from my app in it

**Again, it's one of those argh, a ghost issues, if anyone has a hunch where to hunt for it, you'll make me VERY happy**

:-/

Comment: To whoever downvoted, please let me know what to fix in the question, tia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duping the key from hash iterator fixed it for me,

```
# pages
STATIC_PAGES.each do |slug, desc|
  match ":language/#{slug}" => 'pages#static_page', :defaults => {:slug => slug.dup, :language => 'en'}, :via => :get, :as => slug.underscore.to_s
end
```

problem here was that `STATIC_PAGES` is a hash constant with `String` keys, it's keys are frozen. In cases of requests for which route defaults kicked in the router tried to do something with the frozen `slug` string stored in `:defaults => {:slug => slug` - something in the rails 3.0 => rails 3.2.16 changelog introduced a modification of this value and shiny exceptions happened in the ActionDispatch stack.

"Unfreezing" `slug` by doing `slag.dup` fixed the issue